# Getting all options in a multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using bootstrap-multiselect and I want to get all the options (not just selected ones) for a given multiselect. I know I can get the selected ones using the following code:

```
var options = $('#myMultiselect option:selected');
```

But I am not sure how to get ALL the options and not just selected ones.

Effectively, I want to dynamically modify the list of options based on some event and thus want to get hold of the list so that I can modify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var options = $('#myMultiselect option');`

Comment: this works !!! Will choose the answer after time allows. I was trying :option and option:

Comment: i didnt get your question

Comment: There is no question. I was just saying that instead of using $('#myMultiselect option'); I was trying $('#myMultiselect :option'); and $('#myMultiselect option:'); which were not working. All I had to do was get rid of :

Comment: That will not work... If in the case checkbox you can call it as ` $('input:checkbox')`

Answer (score 1):

You could store all the options in a new array using the following code:

```
var allOptions = new Array;
$('#myMultiselect option').each(function(){
      allOptions.push($(this).val());
});

alert(allOptions);
```

Comment: Manish I am not leaving. SO wants me to wait for some time before choosing an answer. By the way, I saw Nithin's answer first, which is same as yours, so I will choose that as accepted answer. I hope you don't mind